# Joomla 3.0 Frontpage Determination Function

Tags: joomla

I've got a joomla template that uses this code to determine which is frontpage i guess

```
function xtcIsFrontpage() {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive(); $activeid = $active ? $active->id : '';
    $default = $menu->getDefault(); $defaultid = $default ? $default->id : 0;
    return ( $activeid == $defaultid );
}
```

the problem is i use multilanguage on this project and when I browse to home pages for the languages they are not known as frontpage but innerpage.How can i force the template to use those menus defaults as frontpage.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've Corrected the code myself :D

```
function xtcIsFrontpage() {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $active = $menu->getActive(); $activeid = $active ? $active->id : '';
    $default = $menu->getDefault($lang->getTag()); $defaultid = $default ? $default->id : 0;
    return ( $activeid == $defaultid );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code and link to account for languages.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

```
<?php 
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu(); 
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage(); 
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault($lang->getTag())) { 
    echo 'This is the front page';
} else {
    echo 'Accueil';
} ?>
```

Comment: how to combine these two blocks of code to meet my needs?